# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Knight' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I have no clue why this doesn't want to cooperate when the rest of the code using MySQL works perfectly, It's just when I try to set a string.

The MySQLManager class:

http://pastebin.com/RWavasPh

I do alter a table to add another column in:

```
try
{
    McInfected.getMySQLManager().execute("ALTER TABLE McInfected ADD Rank VARCHAR(20);");
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
}
```

Then my RanksManager class(The one that gets an sets the ranks)

http://pastebin.com/T0nRKkv7

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am almost ready to throw my computer...

I have tried to look at the other questions for an answer but I'm not really able to understand how to fix it in my instance, As far as I could tell it had to do with the access type, but I'm not to sure what to do to fix it...

This is the error

`11:29:49 PM [WARNING] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Knight' in 'field list'
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
11:29:49 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:779)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:622)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at com.bimmr.mcinfected.MySQL.MySQLManager.updateString(MySQLManager.java:338)
11:29:50 PM [WARNING]   at me.bimmr.mcinfectedranks.Ranks.RankManager.setPlayersRank(RankManager.java:173)`

Comment: You are passing a invalid column name in updateString() method of MySqlManager class. Please check what you are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySqlManager.updateString `value` is not quoted, neither escaped.

```
this.statement.execute("UPDATE " + tableName
    + " SET " + columnName + "=" + value
    + " WHERE UUID ='" +
```

should be:

```
this.statement.execute("UPDATE " + tableName
    + " SET " + columnName + "='" + value.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
    + "' WHERE UUID ='" +
```

Better yet: use a PreparedStatement to do the escaping and safe-guard against SQL-injection.